# Launch a program when any wireless connection comes up using netcfg

Tags: netcfg

I have written a program that transparently logs in to captive portals. As such, I'd like to run this any time that any wireless connection comes up using [netcfg](https://www.archlinux.org/netcfg/netcfg.8.html). It is possible to do this per-connection in the configuration file by using `POST_UP`, but this would require adding it to every connection that currently exists, and any connection that may be created in future, which is not feasible in my situation. I also do not wish to poll for network connections as a daemon. I don't see any information about doing this in [`man netcfg-profiles`](https://www.archlinux.org/netcfg/netcfg-profiles.5.html).

How should I approach this? Does netcfg have any built-in configuration that allows a `POST_UP` to apply to multiple connections?

It is acceptable for it to also apply to all connections (including wired), but if possible I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interface-specific {PRE,POST}_{UP,DOWN} commands can be defined in /etc/network.d/interfaces/$DEVICE, where $DEVICE is your network device name.
So, although you need a hook per interface (which is actually what you indicate that you want), you do not need one per connection.

For example, my interfaces folder has the following files:

#### /etc/network.d/interfaces/_functions:

```
notify() {
dev="$1"
state="$2"
/usr/local/sbin/xuserrun /usr/local/sbin/network_notification "$dev" "$state"
return 0
}
```

#### /etc/network.d/interfaces/{wlan0,eth0} (both with same contents):

```
source /etc/network.d/interfaces/_functions
POST_UP="notify ${INTERFACE} up"
PRE_DOWN="notify ${INTERFACE} down"
```

This runs a script to send a pop-up notification telling me when a connection has been made/lost. Note that these hooks run as the root user. The `xuserrun` command is available on [github](http://github.com/rephorm/xuserrun) and determines the current X username and switches to that user before running the subsequent command.